# Shell Script & progressIndicator - AppleScript

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript

What I have is an applescript app in xcode that runs a shell script. What I was hoping to do is have the progressIndicator move a certain amount when the command is "echo hello world" as an example but since all of my commands are sudo I have to put them in a shell script together and I can't just have the progressIndicator move in between commands (there are lots of them.) Is there a way to have the bar move when a certain command is started? Also, is there a way to output the log of the applescript to a textView in xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You can always run the command line tool "ps" to see which processes are currently running. As such you can formulate a repeat loop and using ps can figure out which of your commands are currently running... and thus increment your progress indicator as needed.

Here's a ps command I've used to get a nice listing. You can combine this with grep to filter for your processes...

```
/bin/ps -Axcro user,pid,%cpu,command
```